# Errors while building GLAD with gcc

Tags: c, opengl, glad

i'm having troubles with GLAD. I've downloaded the source files with [this configuration](http://glad.dav1d.de/#profile=core&specification=gl&api=gl%3D4.6&api=gles1%3Dnone&api=gles2%3Dnone&api=glsc2%3Dnone&language=c&loader=on):

- Language - C/C++
- Specification - OpenGL
- API - gl Version 4.6
- Profile - Core
- Generate loader is checked

After unpacking the archive i got this structure (made it as simple as possible for now):

```
project/
    main.c
    glad.h
    glad.c
    khrplatform.h
```

My `main.c` is something like this:

```
#include "./glad.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

And finally, i've tried compiling it with `gcc`, because my project is going to be in `c`:

```
gcc main.c glad.c -lglfw -lGL -ldl -I. -o run
```

But i got these errors:

```
glad.c:1328:1: error: unknown type name ‘PFNGLRENDERBUFFERSTORAGEMULTISAMPLEEXTPROC’; did you mean ‘PFNGLRENDERBUFFERSTORAGEMULTISAMPLEPROC’?
 1328 | PFNGLRENDERBUFFERSTORAGEMULTISAMPLEEXTPROC glad_glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleEXT = NULL;
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      | PFNGLRENDERBUFFERSTORAGEMULTISAMPLEPROC
glad.c:1328:87: warning: initialization of ‘int’ from ‘void *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 1328 | PFNGLRENDERBUFFERSTORAGEMULTISAMPLEEXTPROC glad_glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleEXT = NULL;
      |                                                                                       ^~~~
glad.c: In function ‘load_GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample’:
glad.c:2441:46: error: ‘PFNGLRENDERBUFFERSTORAGEMULTISAMPLEEXTPROC’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘PFNGLRENDERBUFFERSTORAGEMULTISAMPLEPROC’?
 2441 |  glad_glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleEXT = (PFNGLRENDERBUFFERSTORAGEMULTISAMPLEEXTPROC)load("glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleEXT");
      |                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                              PFNGLRENDERBUFFERSTORAGEMULTISAMPLEPROC
glad.c:2441:46: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
glad.c:2441:89: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘load’
 2441 |  glad_glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleEXT = (PFNGLRENDERBUFFERSTORAGEMULTISAMPLEEXTPROC)load("glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleEXT");
      |                                                                                         ^~~~
      |                                                                                         ;
```

This code really seems odd for me, but it's from the library, so chaning it on my own doesn't look really good...

Comment: can you give us the permalink to this configuration? The `glad.c` I have has only 1834 lines and not 2441

Comment: Of course, @genpfault, [here](http://glad.dav1d.de/#profile=core&specification=gl&api=gl%3D4.6&api=gles1%3Dnone&api=gles2%3Dnone&api=glsc2%3Dnone&language=c&loader=on) it is

Comment: You wanted to @kaios, I only edited the question :)

Comment: Oopsie.. my bad

Comment: How many lines does your `glad.c` file contains? In the file generated by your link, there are no ext versions of the variables`glad_glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleEXT`. Maybe try to redownload it, and compile it again?

Comment: @kaios, maaan.... i don't know what kinda magic is that, but it actually works)

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to download the correct configuration of GLAD, it's going to be okay.